# Did I mess up my front brake pressure?

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

My Bike:
Ghost - HYBRIDE KATO 3 AL 29

The first problem was that my front brake disc grinded on the brake.

1. I tried to adjust the brake -> didn't work
2. Then I replaced the braking pads which also didn't had an impact
3. out off inexperience, I removed the tire and looked at the brakes and pulled them

The brake block came out of it and some drops of oil came out.
I pushed them back in.

Now my brake pressure is not as good as before.

And I wonder how bad did I screwed up ?

Do I have to buy braking oil to remove air out of the braking system or what can I do that the pressure is getting better again?

In the end I just made it worse and my braking pads are still grinding the brake disk.

My guess what be:

1. Yes pressure is down and get the air out of the braking system.
2. Remove the braking disk (cant really see it) as it might be a bit bended
3. (Maybe the braking disk is just not in the right position)

[image: Bike Disk]

[image: Brake Pressure]

Comment: "I tried to adjust the brake" — Could you elaborate on exactly what you did here? Also, when you say "The brake block came out of it", are you referring to the cylindrical black plastic brake pistons? If those popped out, you've lost all the oil in your caliper. I'd be surprised if you had any brake pressure remaining at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fixable, but as well as brake oil you'll need a bleed kit.  You may want to take it to a bike shop that already has one, rather than buying the tools.

There's a chance you've got oil on your (new) pads, so they might need replacing again.  There's also a chance of oil on the rotor, but that can likely be cleaned.

Was the main symptom of the "grinding" a noise?  It's possible something is very worn and parts that shouldn't make contact are touching.  But from the photos, I suspect it's more a little brake rub, which can sometimes go away by re-tightening your front wheel (especially with quick-release wheels) or may need a tiny adjustment to the brake mounting.  This should be done after bleeding them.

Having looked at the videos, and more importantly listened, the rotor is only lightly and intermittently contacting something.  I don't think it's significantly warped, and I think what it's touching is the inner pad.  Once bled, you should be able to loosen the mounting screws, squeeze the lever fairly hard, and tighten the screw with the lever held.  This will recentre the caliper.

Comment: Sad so guess "bleeding" is the only option there are no screws to tighten or ? Kit from amazon I wanted to buy [the kit](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B091FWHR2W/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=AUR2JCS4DU08&psc=1). I made two videos from the "grinding" noise, I think its the brake itself. [linke to videos (shared icloud link)](https://share.icloud.com/photos/0beEMsakQY26chZvDlaSqqKlw) The next steps would be. 01. Buy and use Bleeding kit 02. adjust the brake (I dont thing its just brake rub). Im not sure how I can adjust the brake properly as I already tried it quite a lot ...

Comment: @Schwenk I would start by adjusting the brakes and then if that doesn’t work deal with getting the bleed kit. Adjusting the brakes yourself is free and relatively easy, so even if it doesn’t fix things, you aren’t spending anything but your time.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn it sounds like if it didn't need bleeding before, it does now.

Comment: @Schwenk You lost some oil from the system. No amount of turning screws is going to make it go back into the system.

Comment: I fixed the braking noise and the bleeding kit is coming today. Thanks everyone